# 'make' and 'make guile' packages in ubuntu

Tags: command-line, make

I am using 'make' to install a simulator but it says:
"The program 'make' can be found in the following packages:
*make
*make-guile."
What does it mean? what exactly i need to do here?

Comment: What "simulator" are you trying to install?

Comment: Its Disksim-4.0

Comment: See `apt show make` and `apt show make-guile` to see the differences between the two packages. Seems like you might be in a bit over your head, look up how to use 'make', what it does, and why it's used before proceeding.

Answer (score 2):

I came here with the same question. :-D

make-guile is a variant of make that adds gnu guile support.

##### What is gnu guile?

It looks like an implementation of the Scheme programming language.
https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/

##### So how does that affect make?

It appears that it allows you to write make functions in scheme.
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Guile-Integration.html